# PL/SQL Procedure containing cursor taking too much time

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, query-optimization, database-cursor

I am facing some problem. I have created a procedure with cursor. It is actually a scheduled job which is called from Java(Quartz). The procedure also creates logging which is sent as a mail to the admin. It runs fine but it is taking too much time. The main work of the procedure is to delete some 20k records from different tables. WHat the procedure is doing :

- 1: Creating a cursor with selecting number of columns from two
  tables.
- 2: Looping through the cursor and collecting all the data in the out
  parameter. close the cursor.
- Open the cursor again
- 5: Deleting    records from 15/20 tables(I need to delete records
  from one parent    table but since it has many child tables i need to
  clean them also    and hence so many delete queries)( I cant provide
  15 tables create    table queries)
- 6: Also calculating the time because the script should    run only
  for 3,5 hrs and after that it should just break the loop and    set a
  status.
- 7: if it cannot delete the records then also it should log the
  details in the out parameter.
- 8: The out parameter i am sending    to the java code so that i can
  send a mail with the data.

My procedure:

```sql
  CURSOR cur_rec
        IS
          SELECT
    "A1"."records_NR"      "records_NR",
    "A2"."employer_NR"     "employer_NR",
    "A2"."Name"   "name",
     "A1"."records_Date"      "Date"
FROM
    
    "t_employer"   "A2",
   "t_records"    "A1"
WHERE
    "A1"."WG_ID" = "A2"."ID"
    AND "A1"."records_DATE" < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, - (5*12)) AND "A1"."SS_ID" = 2411287;

TYPE recSet IS TABLE OF cur_rec%ROWTYPE;
   rec_rec recSet;
v_rec_rec cur_rec%ROWTYPE;



BEGIN

SAVEPOINT DEL_rec;


result := 'Start time ;' || extract(hour from v_start) || ':' || extract(minute from v_start) || ':' || extract(second from v_start) || chr(10) ;

result := result ||'records(S)' || chr(10);

result := result ||'records NUMMER'||';'||'NAAM'||';'||'employer '||';' ||'DATE'|| chr(10);

 
OPEN cur_rec;
LOOP
FETCH cur_rec INTO v_rec_rec;
exit WHEN cur_rec%NOTFOUND;


result := result || to_clob(v_rec_rec.records_nr) || ';' || to_clob(v_rec_rec.name) || ';' || to_clob(v_rec_rec.employer_nr) || ';' || to_clob(v_rec_rec.Date) || chr(10);

end loop;
CLOSE cur_rec;





result := result ||'Skipped records(S)' || chr(10);


result := result ||'records '||';'||'NAME'||';'||'employer '||';'||'Date' || chr(10);



<<cursor_loop>>
FOR rec IN cur_rec
    LOOP

    
 DELETE
      FROM TEST BD
      WHERE BD.ID IN (SELECT S.ID FROM t_records A, t_bem b,t_steps S
      WHERE A.ID = b.vce_id AND S.bmg_id = b.ID  AND A.records_NR = rec.records_nr);

      DELETE
      FROM t_reason TN
      WHERE TN.BMG_ID IN (SELECT b.ID FROM t_records A, t_bem b
      WHERE A.ID = b.vce_id AND A.records_NR = rec.records_nr);


    ..... similar 15 delete queries
    
      COMMIT;

    v_end :=  SYSTIMESTAMP;
    v_diff_ms := ( extract(hour from   (v_end - v_start)) * 3600 +
                              extract(minute from (v_end - v_start)) * 60   +
                              extract(second from (v_end - v_start))
                            ) ;

    select count(*) into v_count from t_records a where a.records_nr = rec.records_nr;

    IF(v_count = 0)
    THEN
    COUNT_rec_DELETED := COUNT_rec_DELETED + 1;

    ELSE
            

             result := result || to_clob(rec.records_nr) || ';' || to_clob(rec.name)|| ';' ||to_clob(rec.employer_nr) || ';' ||to_clob(rec.Date) || chr(10);
    END IF;


    IF(v_diff_ms > max_time) THEN
    BEGIN
   SELECT
    "A1"."records_NR",
    "A2"."employer_NR",
    "A2"."name",
     "A1"."expiry date" BULK COLLECT INTO rec_rec
FROM
    "employer"   "A2",
 t_records"    "A1"
WHERE
    "A1"."WG_ID" = "A2"."ID"
    AND "A1"."expiry date" < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, - (5*12)) AND "A1"."VIS_ID" = 2411287;
    END;

    FOR i IN rec_rec.FIRST .. rec_rec.LAST
            loop
            BEGIN
               result := result ||to_clob(rec_rec(i).records_nr) || ';' || to_clob(rec_rec(i).name)|| ';' ||to_clob(rec_rec(i).employer_nr) || ';' ||to_clob(rec_rec(i).Date)|| chr(10);
               END;
            end loop;

    EXIT cursor_loop;

         END IF;

   END LOOP;


        IF v_diff_ms IS NULL OR
           v_diff_ms <= max_time
        THEN

           status := 'OK';
        ELSE

           status := 'More than 3.5 hrs';
        END IF
        ;

    result := result ||'DELETED records(S) COUNT: ' || to_clob(COUNT_rec_DELETED) || chr(10);
    result := result ||'End time ; ' || to_clob(extract(hour from v_end)) || ':' || to_clob(extract(minute from v_end)) || ':' || to_clob(extract(second from v_end))  || chr(10);


EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   result := result ||'----------------------------------------------------------------------------' || chr(10);
   result := result ||'Error' || chr(10);
   result := result ||'ERROR; ' || to_clob(SQLCODE) || '; ' || to_clob(SQLERRM) || chr(10);
   result := result ||'----------------------------------------------------------------------------' || chr(10);
   status := 'ERROR';
END;
```

Any idea why cursor taking that much time. of is it an expected behavoiur?

Comment: You have posted a 4-page PL/SQL script (which has in the middle of it `... similar 15 delete queries` so we don't have the complete script and would need to edit it to get it to run) with minimal description of what it does and have not provided the `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE INDEX` statements for the tables nor any execution plans and you expect us to be able to help you improve its performance? Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] where we can replicate the problem and you might find someone able to help you.

Comment: @MT0                    I have update the question with more details. If i paste 15 delete queries, it would become too big  and cretae table and cretae index for so many tables  is also not handy to paste here. But if it is still not clear i can try to paste the 15 delete queries. Thanks In Advance